# How to capture mysql queries using wireshark

Tags: mysql, wireshark

I am trying to capture mysql queries. server run on localhost:8090 and database is running on localhost:3306.

Console log is:

*INFO: Server startup in [938] milliseconds*

*Query is: select * from film where film_id = '123'.*

*CASABLANCA SUPER A Amazing Panorama of a Crocodile And a Forensic Psychologist who must Pursue a Secret Agent in The First Manned Space Station*

When i send request to server wireshark captures only mysql login request.
[image]
How can i capture the actual query?

Comment: you should enable the [query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html), MySQL will log those queries for you.

Comment: thank you for answer but i need to use wireshark

Comment: Do you have a capture or display filter in place ? Is the connection encrypted ?